# JS anti-onbeforeunload prompt in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have page (with different domain) in iframe on my page. But iframed page have this code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit() {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
}
</script>
```

so i cant close parent page without "You have attempted..." prompt. This is very anoying prompt, anyone have idea how block this kind of prompt?

EDIT: I forgot - JS is very important in child (iframed) page. I cant use use sandboxed mode without JS or forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You need clean whole parent page in parent onbeforeunload event. This erase child iframe with attached onbeforeunload event before it is called.
In your parent page add this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = cleanPage;
function cleanPage() {
    document.write("");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a cross-origin request, you can't access the DOM of the page to remove the event handler.

The closest you could come would be to block *all* JavaScript running within the frame, as per [this other Stackoverflow question](/questions/3689455/disable-javascript-in-iframe-div).

Comment: Sorry, i forgot - JS in child (iframed) page is very important.

Comment: @MilanObrtlík — Then, as I said in the answer, you can't.